# How do I make my exponentiation operator work with all numeric types in Swift?

Tags: swift, operators

I have created a ^^ operator in Swift. How do I make it work with Integers and Doubles like all other operators?

```
infix operator ^^ { }
func ^^ (number:Int, power: Int) -> Int {
    var result = power > 0 ? number : 0
    if power > 1 { for x in 1..<power { result *= number } }
    return result
}
```

Comment: you have to try this   **pow(num, 2)**

Comment: yeah but if you want to square value than that is useful.

Comment: yeah that is useful!

Comment: possible duplicate of [exponentiation operator in SWIFT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065801/exponentiation-operator-in-swift)

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus: You are now mixing problem, (your) solution and analysis all in the *question*. In particular your original question is not visible anymore, which makes my answer (which tried to answer your original problem) useless. A future reader will not understand why a wrote about a "more type-safe version" if all the code in your quesion *is* type-safe (and in fact based on what I suggested in my answer). - I would suggest that you revert the *question* to the **original version**, and put your *solutions* in the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a more type-safe implementation, using operator overloading. For integer types,
you can define `^^` as

```
infix operator ^^ { associativity left precedence 170 }

func ^^<T : IntegerType, U : IntegerType> (base: T, var power: U) -> T {

    if power < 0 { return 0 }

    var result : T = 1
    var square : T = base

    if power > 0 {
        if power % 2 == 1 { result *= square }
        power /= 2
    }
    while power > 0 {
        square *= square
        if power % 2 == 1 { result *= square }
        power /= 2
    }

    return result
}
```

(I have chosen a more efficient variant called "exponentiation by repeated squaring and multiplication".)

For floating point types, define a protocol the covers all types that can be 
converted from and to `Double`:

```
protocol DoubleConvertible {
    init(_ value: Double)
    var doubleValue : Double { get }
}
```

and make `Float`, `Double` and `CGFloat` conform to that protocol:

```
extension Double : DoubleConvertible {
    var doubleValue : Double { return self }
}

extension Float : DoubleConvertible {
    var doubleValue : Double { return Double(self) }
}

extension CGFloat : DoubleConvertible {
    var doubleValue : Double { return Double(self) }
}
```

Now the floating point exponentiation can simply be defined as

```
func ^^<T : DoubleConvertible, U:DoubleConvertible> (base: T, power: U) -> T {

    return T(pow(base.doubleValue, power.doubleValue))
}
```

Examples:

```
let x1 = 2^^3               // Int
let x2 = UInt64(2)^^3       // UInt64 
let x3 = 2.0 ^^ 3           // Double
let x4 = Float(2.0) ^^ 3    // Float
let x5 = "a" ^^ "b"         // Compiler error
```

---

**Update for Swift 4:**

`IntegerType` has become `BinaryInteger` ([SE-0104 Protocol-oriented integers](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0104-improved-integers.md)) and 
the syntax for declaring operators has changed
([SE-0077 Improved operator declarations](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0077-operator-precedence.md).)

Here is an implementation for all integer and floating point
bases with `Int` exponents:

```
precedencegroup ExponentiationPrecedence { associativity: right higherThan: MultiplicationPrecedence }
infix operator ^^: ExponentiationPrecedence

func ^^<T : BinaryInteger>(base: T, power: Int) -> T {
    if power < 0 { return 0 }
    var power = power
    var result: T = 1
    var square = base

    if power > 0 {
        if power % 2 == 1 { result *= square }
        power /= 2
    }
    while power > 0 {
        square *= square
        if power % 2 == 1 { result *= square }
        power /= 2
    }
    return result
}

func ^^(base: Float, power: Int) -> Float {
    return pow(base, Float(power))
}

func ^^(base: Double, power: Int) -> Double {
    return pow(base, Double(power))
}

func ^^(base: CGFloat, power: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return pow(base, CGFloat(power))
}
```

Examples:

```
let x1 = 2^^3            // Int
let x2 = UInt64(2)^^3    // UInt64
let x3 = 2.0 ^^ -3       // Double
let x4 = Float(2.0) ^^ 3 // Float
// let x6 = "a" ^^ 5      // Compiler error
```

See [SE-0104 Protocol-oriented integers](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0104-improved-integers.md)
about the new protocol hierarchy introduced in Swift 4.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus: The problem was that `square *= square` was calculated even in the last step, where the value is not needed anymore. This causes the overflow. I have modified the code, it does now work up to `Int64(2)^^62` and `UInt64(2)^^63`.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus: As you already noticed, this method not really faster than yours, because the exponents are limited to at most 63. Its advantages become more apparent when dealing with *large* exponents.

Comment: @LeoDabus: Updated. With `T: Numeric` the cases of floating point or Decimal bases are covered automatically!

Comment: @LeoDabus: Updated again :) – I have restricted the exponent to type `Int`, but now it works for all base types (integer, float, decimal) correctly, without unnecessary type conversions. I think that is a sensible compromise. (It could be simplified if  `pow()` were generic, but it isn't.)

Comment: `var square: T = 1` should be `var square = base`

Comment: @LeoDabus: Indeed! – I have also remove the version taking a Decimal base, that does not work with negative exponents (returning NaN).