# How to extend arithmetic operators to support optional values as well - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In the below example,

```
let value1: Int? = 23
let value2: Int = 20

let answer = value1 + value2 // Compiler warning that + operator cannot be applied to Int? and Int
```

So I would have to change the code to

```
if let value1 = value1 {
    let answer = value1 + value2 
}
```

How to create an extension for `+` that supports Optional values as well? In that case it should give nil as output.

What if the operation has multiple operands?

```
let value1: Int? = 2

let answer = value1 + 3.0
```

Comment: Your Value1 is optional and in usage you used value 2 for handling optional value. Please Explain.

Comment: If the operation has multiple operands, then the operators will get called multiple times. What's wrong with that?

Comment: The example in your edit `value1 + 3.0` is not an expression with multiple operandi. Do you mean an expression with multiple _types_?

Comment: Yeah we can't do anything on multiple types isn't?

Comment: @Saranjith Well, you _could_, but Swift is designed this way _for a reason_. It is designed to make you aware exactly where conversions are happening. You'd need a _very_ good reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to find the right protocol type to constrain the generic types, really. After that the implementation is trivial:

```
// plus and minus is supported by AdditiveArithmetic
func +<T: AdditiveArithmetic>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> T? {
    return lhs.flatMap { x in rhs.map { y in x + y } }
    /* the above is just a more "functional" way of writing 
    if let x = lhs, let y = rhs {
        return x + y
    } else {
        return nil
    }
    */
}

func -<T: AdditiveArithmetic>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> T? {
    return lhs.flatMap { x in rhs.map { y in x - y } }
}

// times is supported by Numeric
func *<T: Numeric>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> T? {
    return lhs.flatMap { x in rhs.map { y in x * y } }
}

// divide is not supported by a single protocol AFAIK
func /<T: BinaryInteger>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> T? {
    return lhs.flatMap { x in rhs.map { y in x / y } }
}

func /<T: FloatingPoint>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> T? {
    return lhs.flatMap { x in rhs.map { y in x / y } }
}
```

To make `value1 + 3.0` work, you'd have to do something like this:

```
func +<T: BinaryInteger, U: FloatingPoint>(lhs: T?, rhs: U?) -> U? {
    return lhs.flatMap { x in rhs.map { y in U(x) + y } }
}
```

But it's usually not a good idea to go against the restrictions put in place. I don't recommend this.

Comment: let value1: Int? = 2;

let answer = value1 + 3.0

This input is failing

Comment: @Saranjith Why did you expect it work? You are adding a `Double` to an `Int`. If you want to define operators that operate between `Double` and `Int`, that's a completely different question to this. This question is about operators operating on optional types, right?

Comment: @Saranjith You wouldn't be able to do `value1 + 3.0` even if `value1` is non-optional, which is why I feel like your edit kind of turns your question into a totally different one. Do you see what I mean? Is there a reason why you want to implicitly convert from `Int` to `Double`? Swift disallowed this for the very purpose of making sure the programmer knows exactly what conversions they are doing.

Comment: @Sweeper `func +<T: BinaryInteger, U: FloatingPoint>(lhs: T?, rhs: U?) -> U? {` IMO it should return `T` instead of `U`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26797755/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus Is that post supposed to explain why you think it should return `T?`? I don't see how it explains so. Is this some kind of convention in Swift that operators should have the same return type as the first operand? I made it return `U?` because I was trying to match the behaviour in languages like Java and C# (adding `int` and `double` gives you another `double`). Anyway, to actually recreate this behaviour, OP would need another operator that takes `U?` as the first argument and `T?` as second argument, which is why I said I don't recommend this.

Comment: I am just saying the left type should be the resulting type. How would you implement `+=` with that approach? Again this is just my opinion. Didn't say it is "wrong".

Comment: @LeoDabus But would you expect `a + 3.9` where `a` is 1 to give you 4? I wouldn't. I'd expect 4.9.

Comment: well as you already said you don't recomment. I wouldn't either. The result should be an integer in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

Only pasting solution for addition, but other operators will work analogously (but mind subtract and division, since they are *not* [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property))

## Three reasonable solutions

1. Global function(s)
2. Extend *existential*`*` (conforming to `AdditiveArithmetic`) to some new protocol e.g. `AdditiveArithmeticOptional`
3. Extend `Optional`

`*` Note: you can [read about *existentials* here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#generalized-existentials), e.g. `protocol` **isn't** an existential, but a *concrete* type, e.g. a `struct` **is**.

## 1 Global function(s)

See @Sweepers answer

Note: a *global* function is a function not implemented on a type (protocol or existential). Swift's [`zip` function is an example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip)

## 2 Extend *existentials* to new protocol

```swift
public protocol AdditiveArithmeticOptional: AdditiveArithmetic {
    static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self?) -> Self
}

public extension AdditiveArithmeticOptional {

    static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self?) -> Self {
        guard let value = rhs else { return lhs }
        return value + lhs
    }

    static func + (lhs: Self?, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        rhs + lhs
    }
}
extension Int8: AdditiveArithmeticOptional {}
extension Int16: AdditiveArithmeticOptional {}
extension Int32: AdditiveArithmeticOptional {}
extension Int64: AdditiveArithmeticOptional {}
extension Int: AdditiveArithmeticOptional {} // same as `Int64` on 64 bit system, same as `Int32` on 32 bit system

extension UInt8: AdditiveArithmeticOptional {}
extension UInt16: AdditiveArithmeticOptional {}
extension UInt32: AdditiveArithmeticOptional {}
extension UInt64: AdditiveArithmeticOptional {}
extension UInt: AdditiveArithmeticOptional {} // same as `UInt64` on 64 bit system, same as `UInt32` on 32 bit system
```

## 3 extend `Optional`

```swift
extension Optional where Wrapped: AdditiveArithmetic {
    static func + <I>(optional: Self, increment: I) -> I where I: AdditiveArithmetic & ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, I.IntegerLiteralType == Wrapped {
        guard let value = optional else { return increment }
        let base = I.init(integerLiteral: value)
        return base + increment
    }

    static func + <I>(increment: I, optional: Self) -> I where I: AdditiveArithmetic & ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, I.IntegerLiteralType == Wrapped {
        optional + increment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own custom operator function if you have multiple scenarios where you require arithmetic operations between optionals as follows:

```
func + (lhs: Int?, rhs: Int?) -> Int {
    (lhs ?? 0) + (rhs ?? 0)
}
func + (lhs: Int?, rhs: Int) -> Int {
    (lhs ?? 0) + rhs
}
func + (lhs: Int, rhs: Int?) -> Int {
    lhs + (rhs ?? 0)
}
```

Note: Add return keyword if you are using Swift 5 or below.

Update: Upon further investigation and inspiration from the answer of @sweeper following solution seemed more elegant.

```
func + <T: AdditiveArithmetic>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> T {
    (lhs ?? .zero) + (rhs ?? .zero)
}
```

or if you need a nil when operation was not successful

```
func + <T: AdditiveArithmetic>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> T? {
    lhs.flatMap { lhs in rhs.flatMap { lhs + $0 }}
}
```

Comment: you should return nil (Int?) to indicate that operation was not successful rather than returning a 0 which can be a valid result

Answer (score -1):

Optionals don't make much sense to be added, a nil value usually represents something went wrong along the way and a value could not be retrieved. It's better to be explicit, and to write the if-let statements. This way you can handle the cases where you end up with nil values.

But if you want to ignore the nils, then you can use the nil coalescing operator:

```
let value1: Int? = 23
let value2: Int = 20

let answer = (value1 ?? 0) + value2
```

You are still explicit about the unwrap, but you also have a fallback route in case you want to ignore the nil value. And, maybe even more important, the code transmits its scope in a clear manner. If someone later on stumbles upon your code it will be clear to them what the code does and how it recovers from unexpected situations (nil is an unexpected value in regards to the addition)