# Using `**` as exponentiation operator in swift working incorrectly with the `-` operator

Tags: swift, operator-overloading

How can I make the exponentiation operator `**` in Swift behave the same as in other programming languages.

The question [Exponentiation operator in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065801/exponentiation-operator-in-swift) has the following answer which has the highest number of up votes,

```
infix operator ** { associativity left precedence 170 }

func ** (num: Double, power: Double) -> Double{
    return pow(num, power)
}
```

However, `y = -x**2`,

- is interpreted as `(-x)**2 = 4.0` (Swift)
- usually it should be interpreted as `-(x**2) = -4.0` (Expected!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is:

> Unary operators in Swift always take precedence over binary operators.

Here's the source: https://medium.com/swift-programming/facets-of-swift-part-5-custom-operators-1080bc78ccc

Therefore, the expression is always evaluated as `(-x)**2` instead of `-(x**2)`, since `-` is a unary operator and `**` is a binary operator.

Comment: Thanks! I might fill a feature request for that.

Comment: Good idea, it would be nice to see operators evaluated in the order you'd expect!